# Confusing examples; Apostrophe-“s” vs “of ”

Tags: differences, prepositions, possessives, apostrophe, possessive-s-vs-of

[image]

[image]

These examples are very confusing to me and I still can't understand the difference between 's and of. For some sentences, it is grammatically wrong but for some sentences it is correct. Please help me out. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: It's to a large degree idiomatic—native English speakers use whichever "feels" right, and lots of times we can use both. There is an answer which goes into detail on this question.

Comment: It is not _grammatically wrong_  to say 'Is this the umbrella of your friend?'; it is just, as Peter says, not idiomatic. It would sound odd in everyday conversation.